# IntelliJ fails to compile with ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Priority

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just installed IntelliJ on a new Mac OS and trying to compile a very simple basic Java app. Here is what I'm getting:

```
Information:2/5/15, 10:40 AM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 11 sec
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
  at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priority
  at io.netty.util.internal.logging.Log4JLoggerFactory.newInstance(Log4JLoggerFactory.java:29)
  at io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.getInstance(InternalLoggerFactory.java:84)
  at io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.getInstance(InternalLoggerFactory.java:77)
  at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<clinit>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:32)
  at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:96)
  ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Priority
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 10 more
```

Never seen this before. What can I do to fix it? I already installed IntelliJ from scratch.

Comment: I don't see any indication that log4j is on your classpath. Did you check that?

Comment: @dcsohl Do you know how I can check that?

Comment: How exactly did you install IntelliJ IDEA? Looks like your installation is corrupt and is missing some of the jar files.

Comment: The files are all there, including the `log4j.jar`. Do you know where I can fix the classpath of IntelliJ IDEA itself? I tried `Info.plist`, but my changes don't make any effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a file in `/Library/Java/Extensions` called `netty.jar`. I deleted it and the problem disappeared.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with log4j - how did you determine where the problem jar was?

Comment: Okay, I moved everything out of  `/Library/Java/Extensions` and it's now working. You should mark your answer as the accepted solution.

Comment: I have the same error and my `/Library/Java/Extensions` is empty